# How to make module pattern each function a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, module, promise

I use Angular 1.5 and I made a factory function which is return a literal object like this:

```
return {
   item: null,
   get: function() {
     return item;
   },
   create: function() {
     if (this.get()){
         this.remove();
     }

     this.item = {};
   },
   remove: function() {
     var item = this.get();
     if (item) {
      this.item = null;
     }
   },
   add: function() {
     if (!this.get()) {
        this.create();
     }

     this.item.newprop = 'value';
   }
}
```

1. please do not ask me to change to function declaration. I want a object with his own actions(functions) and properties that is working on.
2. This pattern (like `get` inside `create` so on..) I didn't copied from anywhere. so I'm wonder if has a name? It is best way to deal with function-black boxes?
3. What is the best way to put Promise inside? so every function should return a promise
4. every `then` function I need to use `bind`???

   todo like this:

> ```
> create: function () {
>     this.get()
>         .then(remove)
>         .then(function () {
>             this.item = {}; // BUT this === undefined!!
>         });
> }
> ```

Comment: For the promise part of your question, why isn't the answer just that you modify each method to return a promise?  I don't know what you could be asking when you say "what is the best way to put a promise inside"?  You make your async operations return promises and then you if a method uses one of those async operations, you return their promise.

Comment: `// BUT this === undefined!!` - that's due to how "this" works - plenty of information on SO about that - one work around (rather than using bind) is the old `var _this=this;` - or use arrow => functions

Comment: What does `item` in the `get` method refer to?

Comment: Why would you want to make your methods return promises? They are not doing anything asynchronous. Or are they? Then please tell us what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bind in every then callback function:

```js
var myModule = {
    item: null,
    get: function() {              
        return Promise.resolve(this.item);
    },
    create: function() {
        return this.remove().then(function() {
            this.item = {};
        }.bind(this));
    },
    remove: function() {
        return this.get().then(function(item) {
            if (item) {
                this.item = null;
            }
        }.bind(this));              
    },
    add: function() {
        return this.get().then(function(item) {
            return item || this.create();
        }.bind(this)).then(function() {
            this.item.newprop = 'value';
        }.bind(this));
    }
}                   
// Let see it working:
myModule.create().then(function() {
    return myModule.get();
}).then(function(item) {
    console.log("After create: ", item);
    return myModule.remove();
}).then(function() {
    return myModule.get();
}).then(function(item) {
    console.log("After remove: ", item);
    return myModule.add();
}).then(function() {
    return myModule.get();
}).then(function(item) {
    console.log("After add: ", item);
});
```